# how to use my own library c++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, linker

Hi Everyone I have some problems using a test library and i hope if someone could help me.

There is the problem:

this is the hierarchy of the test library :

```
dir : ./include/libhello/hello.hxx
dir : ./src/hello.hxx
dir : ./CMakeLists
```

with cmake i generated the `/hello.so`

But now i have problems with using it for an external program `prog.cc`

can you please tell me how can link the prog with `.so` and create the executable et thanks a lot for your response . :)

Answer (score 1):

You might copy the library to /usr/local/lib and the linker should pick it up if you add it to the project.

In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
function(import_library target name)
    find_library(${target}_import_${name} ${name})
    add_library(${${target}_import_${name}} SHARED IMPORTED)
    target_link_libraries(${target} ${name})
endfunction()

function(project_import_library name)
    import_library(Project ${project})
endfunction(

project_import_library(dependency)
```

Replace Project/project and dependency by your names.